# Passing a pointer to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, pointers

Is there any way to pass a pointer to a list, so I could have
`update_list(list, data)`

Instead of having to do
`list = update_list(list, data)`

Independent of whether this is possible, what is advisable and Pythonic in this situation?

Comment: I'm wondering if your data is also a list? If so, you might consider original_list.extend(new_list). This would be very "pythonix", because its simple, explicit and beautiful. ;-)

Comment: also something as simple as `list += data` may work for you if you are just extending the list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend reading [Semantics of Python variable names from a C++ perspective](http://rg03.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/semantics-of-python-variable-names-from-a-c-perspective/):

> **All variables are references**

This is oversimplification of the entire article, but this (and the understanding that a `list` is a **mutable** type) should help you understand how the following example works.

```
In [5]: def update_list(lst, data):
   ...:     for datum in data:
   ...:         lst.append(datum)
   ...:         

In [6]: l = [1, 2, 3]

In [7]: update_list(l, [4, 5, 6])

In [8]: l
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You can even shorten this by using the extend() method:

```
In [9]: def update_list(lst, data):
   ...:     lst.extend(data)
   ...:
```

Which actually probably removes the need of your function.

**N.B:** [`list`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/functions.html#list) is a built-in and therefore a bad choice for a variable name.

Comment: I see.  So immutable objects are copied when passed by reference, but mutable objects are not?  If this is the case, then why even speak of immutable objects as being passed by reference?  If effectively they're passed by value in all relevant circumstances..

Comment: Indeed. To say all variables are references is vastly oversimplifying things, but since there are a small number of mutable types, it makes sense for most cases.

Answer (score 4):

You don't pass pointers in Python. Just assign to the slice that is the whole list

```
def update_list(list, data):
    list[:] = newlist
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just make sure to use proper variable names (`list` is a type):

```
>>> def update_list(lst):
...   lst.append('hello')
... 
>>> a = []
>>> update_list(a)
>>> a
['hello']
>>>
```

I'm not a big fan of modifying things in-place and I would actually prefer the second method over the first.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from taking into account that a `list` is mutable and that you can modify it in place inside other functions, as has been already pointed out by other answers; if you're writing many `update_list` methods, you have to consider if the data that is being stored is not really a list but something else that fits into the model you've created as part of the object oriented approach to the problem.

If that's the case, then by all means create your own class and methods to provide the interface that you need to the internal state of your object:

```
class MyList(list):
    def update(self, data):
        # Whatever you need to update your data

...

my_list = MyList()
my_list.update(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This StackOverflow question and subsequent accepted response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) will guide you in the right direction to understanding the Pythonic way of what Python does with values passed in.

In general, the Pythonic way to update the list would be to write/call `update_list(list, data)`.